# Python format timedelta object to datetime

Tags: python

Below is datetime object.

```
datetime_obj = datetime.strptime("2020-11-15T00:00:00.000Z", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
```

When i do the below code

```
str(datetime_obj + timedelta(days=1))
```

It changes format also. I mean it returns this:

```
2020-11-16 00:00:00
```

But expected output should be the below. How can i solve it ?

```
2020-11-16T00:00:00.000Z
```

Thanks for answering

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `str(...)`, but use [`datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) (the serializing counterpart to [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) deserialization) with your original format string:

```
new_datetime = datetime_obj + timedelta(days=1)

print(new_datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'))
# 2020-11-16T00:00:00.000000Z
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `strftime()`

```
(datetime_obj + timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
```

```
'2020-11-16T00:00:00.000000Z'
```

or

```py
(datetime_obj + timedelta(days=1)).isoformat() + 'Z'
```

```
'2020-11-16T00:00:00Z'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either use `strftime` as suggested in the previous answers or the following will also work.

```
>>> new_datetime = datetime_obj + timedelta(days=1)
>>> f"{new_datetime:%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ}" # By using f-strings(3.6+)
'2020-11-16T00:00:00.000000Z'
>>> "{:%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ}".format(new_datetime) # Or by using string.format method
'2020-11-16T00:00:00.000000Z'
```